# Accessing a static atomic data member causes a linker error

Tags: c++, static, linker-errors, atomic

How should a static atomic variable be accessed without causing a linker error?

I've reduced my code example to the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

class MyClass
{
public:
    static std::atomic_bool onOrOff;
};

std::atomic_bool onOrOff(false);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::cout << "It is: " << (MyClass::onOrOff? "on": "off") << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This results in the following linker error (MaxOS X 10.11, XCode 7.2):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "MyClass::onOrOff", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

NB: There are no build errors if I remove the line in main() accessing
`MyClass::onOrOff`, so I think that rules out problems with compiler options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
std::atomic_bool onOrOff(false);
```

Should be:

```
std::atomic_bool MyClass::onOrOff(false);
```

As it stands you have declared two different `onOrOff` variables, one inside the class and one outside.  And only allocated storage for one.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. And I'll give myself the D'oh! award of the day :-)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot that `onOrOff` is a scoped name to `MyClass`.  You need

```
std::atomic_bool MyClass::onOrOff(false);
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://ideone.com/JZJDKH)</kbd>